# How to query: "for which do these values apply"?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I'm trying to match and align data, or resaid, count occurrences and then list for which values those occurrences occur.

Or, in a question: "How many times does each ID value occur, and for what names?"

For example, with this input

```
Name    ID
-------------
jim     123
jim     234
jim     345
john    123
john    345
jane    234
jane    345
jan    45678
```

I want the output to be:

```
count    ID    name    name    name
------------------------------------
3       345    jim    john    jane
2       123    jim    john
2       234    jim    jane
1       45678    jan
```

Or similarly, the input could be (noticing that the ID values are not aligned),

```
jim    john    jane    jan
----------------------------
123    345    234    45678
234    123    345        
345
```

but that seems to complicate things.

As close as I am to the desired results is in SQL, as

```
for ID, count(ID)
from table
group by (ID)
order by count desc
```

which outputs

```
ID    count
------------
345    3
123    2
234    2
45678    1
```

I'll appreciate help.

Comment: Using `dplyr` you could do `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), 
            name = toString(Name))` Do you want the answer in `R` or `sql` ? For `R` this is a duplicate.

Comment: I would like the answer in SQL. I tagged R, too, because I was unsure if SQL can achieve the objective.

Comment: you mean sql server or mysql

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL via PgAdmin query editor. Which would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a pivot.  In SQL, you have to specify the number of columns in advance (unless you construct the query as a string).

But the idea is:

```
select ID, count(*) as cnt,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then name end) as name_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum  -- arbitrary ordering
      from table t
     ) t
group by ID
order by count desc;
```

If you have an unknown number of columns, you can aggregate the values into an array:

```
select ID, count(*) as cnt,
       array_agg(name order by name) as names
from table t
group by ID
order by count desc
```

Comment: Your first answer achieves what I had inquired. Could a query command be added that will cause the values outputed to the `seqnum` columns to be ordered alphabetically, laterally across from left to right, and for the names to placed in the new columns based on their alphabetical position in the total number of names, such as the first name always goes to the first column, and the third name to the third, even if the second name is not an occurrence for that ID? Maybe this is best posted as a new question.

Comment: @GalenFarrel . . . That might be better posted as a new question.  But I think that just changing the `order by id` to `order by name` will do what you want.  (If not, ask a new question).

Comment: Changing `order by id` to `order by name` solved the first part, and I posted a new question, linked below,  which may get me the rest of the way. Thank you for your help, @Gordon.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436165/sql-pivot-assign-names-to-specific-columns-and-order-alphabetically-across-col

Answer (score 0):

the query would look similar to this if that's what you're looking for.

```
SELECT
  name,
  id,
  COUNT(id) as count
FROM
  dataSet
WHERE
  dataSet.name = 'input'
  AND dataSet.id = 'input'
GROUP BY
  name,
  id
```